# Trying to write a list as table to a .tex file with lazyWeave

Tags: r, latex

I'm trying to write a list to a .tex file with lazyWeave in R

I'm able to create the .tex files and write some text to it. But when I'm trying to write the list to a table using `lazy.table()` and `lazy.write()` i got an error. Here some of my code:

```
header = c("PatID", "FUID", "ZID", "SJC28N", "SJC28N.new")
tableHeader <- lazy.table(x = header, open = TRUE, close = FALSE)
lazy.write(
  tableHeader,
  OutFile = "Out.tex",
      append=TRUE
  )
```

if i try to run this in my script, tableHeader remains NULL and this error occurs, when `lazy.write(tableHeader)` is reached:

ERROR: Error in ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos] : 
replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(no, length.out = len) :

But if i run `tableHeader <- lazy.table(x = header, open = TRUE, close = FALSE)`into my console i got an output like this:

```
\begin{table}[h]
%% \usecounter{}
\begin{center}\normalsize
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{PatID} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{FUID} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ZID} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{SJC28N} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{SJC28N.new}\\
```

i can paste this into a .tex file and compile it to a document with a table. But i have no clue why i cant do this in my script. Maybe someone can help me :)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  That is, provide us with a sample of what `ldwrong` looks like.

Comment: I edited my question to provide some data. the outfile works great. Something must be wrong with the table. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You still need to provide what `ldwrong` is.  It's a list, correct?  If so, provide a way to reproduce that list, e.g., `idwrong <- list(1, 2, "a")`

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question again. Now i just use a normal string to name the outfile. But now I'm just using `xtables` to write a table to my .tex file. I think something is broken with `lazy.table`, 'cause the example from the help don't even work.